# Pass PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP variable I want to add in Javascript, the problem is it's not getting the variable, please help I'm new to javascript.  Sorry I think I did not explain very good.

At the moment I have three select boxes displaying Year, month, date the value of $row_info['birth'] is 2011-04-01. When I apply date to defaultDate: the value is not in there.

```
<?php
    $date = $row_info['birth'];
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
    echo("date = '{$row_info['birth']}';\n");
    echo("</script>");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#picker3").birthdaypicker({
        dateFormat: "bigEndian",
        monthFormat: "short",
        placeholder: false,
        defaultDate: date,
        hiddenDate: true
      });
  });
</script>
```

I would really appreciate some help, thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting the variable"?  What happens if you do a `echo($row_info['birth'] . "<br />");`?

Comment: You should be working out what JS you expect the PHP to generate, and then comparing that to what your code is actually generating. You shouldn't be throwing down a blob of PHP and saying it "doesn't work".

Comment: possible duplicate of the entire Related section to the right

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
    $date = $row_info['birth'];
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>\n");
    echo("date = '{".$row_info['birth']."}';\n");
    echo("</script>");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#picker3").birthdaypicker({
        dateFormat: "bigEndian",
        monthFormat: "short",
        placeholder: false,
        defaultDate: date,
        hiddenDate: true
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is taking away my select boxes.

Comment: I don't understand the amount of upvotes. I don't think this is the supposed output: `date = '{2011-04-01}';`

Comment: It won't even output that since `+` is used instead of `.`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
date = <?php echo $row_info['birth'];?>;
$("#picker3").birthdaypicker({
    dateFormat: "bigEndian",
    monthFormat: "short",
    placeholder: false,
    defaultDate: date,
    hiddenDate: true
  });
});
</script>
```